# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShellOpenDocument error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Problem: error message `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShellOpenDocument` after renaming a form.

I installed Visual Studio 2022, created a Visual Basic - Windows - Desktop - Windows Forms-App and started the app: the form is displayed. Then I right click on `Form1.vb`, rename the form to `frmTest` and answer the question if all references should be updated with `Yes`. Result: an error message says that service `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIShellOpenDocument` isn't running.

What I tried:

- tried it with .NET 5.0, .NET 6.0
- searched the web for any hint on that service. Didn't find a solution.
- tried the same with Visual Studio 2019: that works.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/The-service-MicrosoftVisualStudioShel/1626404?space=8&q=IVsUIShellOpenDocument

Comment: Thanks! That did it. When I close the form before renaming, the error is gone.